# Make "default" wordpress pages & features unaccessible

Tags: pages, security, front-end

I am trying to create specific password-protected mini-sites (single wordpress pages) for specific users or specific passwords to be precise. For example someone clicks the url **domain.com/url1** and if he has the password for this page, he can view it. This is fairly simple by using the simple password protection built-in feature of wordpress.

Now the tricky part is that I don't want this person to be able to enter any other part of the *domain.com* wordpress installation. Obviously there won't be any visible menus, but someone could hit **domain.com/s** and go to the search page or to the 404 page.

At the moment I will be disabling the search feature of wordpress, i will empty the archives pages and the 404 page.

Is there any other way/url someone could directly open a "standard" wordpress page besides the login and wp-admin section?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the wrong way around and always having the danger of forgetting or misconfiguring something. If you need content separation, just use a network install. It has a little more overhead of admin but it out of the box ensures the content separation you seek.

Comment: It definitely is a wrong way but wordpress came to the rescue for other reasons so this is something worth checking out. What do you mean by saying a network install?

Comment: how to create one, with hopefully enough links to explain it http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network